# How to count number of checkboxes selected in powerbuider?

Tags: checkbox, count, powerbuilder, datawindow

Can somebody tell me, please, how can I get the number of the selected checkboxes from a datawindow in powerbuilder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the rows looking for the value you have designated as the 'Datavalue for On' for the field with the editstyle of checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Other possibility, without programming:

1. Define the values for on and off at 1 and 0, respectively
2. Add a computed field of arbirary name with as formula: `sum(checkbox_name for all)` (it can be visible or not)

Done.

You can access the value of this sum by its name (`getitemnumber`).

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop to count those checkbox you selected.